# Можно ли одновременно использовать методы onTouch и onClick?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В моем коде:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMoveLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.move);
        mImageView = (ImageView) mMoveLayout.findViewById(R.id.solar);

        //Создаем программно RelativeLayout с параметрами 100*100:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

        //Применяем эти параметры к нашему изображению:
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        //И настраиваем ему слушателя (обработчик) прикосновений:
        mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    //Обрабатываем прикосновения к объекту:
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        //Определение координат через getRawX() и getRawY() дает
        //координаты по отношению к размерам экрана устройства:
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            //ACTION_DOWN срабатывает при прикосновении к экрану,
            //здесь определяется начальное стартовое положение объекта:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                mX = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                mY = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;

            //ACTION_MOVE обрабатывает случившиеся в процессе прикосновения изменения, здесь
            //содержится информация о последней точке, где находится объект после окончания действия прикосновения ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - mX;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - mY;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.solar:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivitySolar.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Я хочу использовать два метода для ImageView, т.е. перемещать (onTouch) и нажатие(onClick) для перехода на другой активити. Активити создал. 
Но не работает.
*Почему, когда я кликаю на ImageView(R.id.solar) не открывается другое активити ?*

Comment: Имеете в виду дописать case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                return false; ? Все равно не получается...

Comment: `onTouch()` должен возвращать `false` после работы. Это говорит о том, что действие не до конца обработано и оно будет передано другим колбэкам, реагирующим на касания (в том числе `onClick()`)/ При возврате `true` дается сигнал, что  дальнейшая обработка касания не требуется.

Comment: @pavlofff при false перестает всё работать. Не могу передвинуть и не реагирует на клик.

Comment: `true` возвращайте, только когда обработали (в `if`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19539206/7566397